# How do I merge specific files from a non-origin repository?

Tags: git

I use gulp for my development environment mainly to minify and optimize code and images/docs. I have created a configurable project template with a dummy website just to test, which has its own Git repo. I have a client project that uses this template, and as I make improvements to the template repo, I would like to merge those changes into my client project repo. However, I only need to pull the two gulp files, not the whole repo.

I have set up the repo as a non-origin remote and tried this:

```
git fetch template master
git checkout -m template/master gulpfile.js gulp.config.js
```

...but this just gives me the two files exactly as they are in the template repo and gets rid of all of the configurations that I had set up in the client repo.

How can I merge changes from the template repo into the client repo while keeping the configurations I have set for the client repo?

Comment: [sync a fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork). `git merge template/master`. If you only change one file in the template project this should be fine?

Comment: Did you commit the changes in the client repo?  If so, you should have some diffs after fetch/checkout.  Merge them.

Comment: part of the problem for this project at least is that I didn't clone the project from the template repo when I started using the template, so it doesn't have any of the commits from the template project. Going forward for new client projects I'll have to do that. Even so, if I make changes to the dummy website, isn't that going to mess up the source code of my client website when I git merge template/master? is there a way to specify specific files?

Comment: Maybe you could cherry pick the relevant commits from the template repo?

Comment: I had to look up what cherry-picking was but yea, I think that's a good solution as long as a remember to keep the two gulp files I want to update in a separate commit from the dummy website. thanks!